# Problemas al subir checkboxes a la base de datos

Tags: mysql, php7

compañeros. Necesito ayuda con subir checkboxes a una base de datos. Es una tabla para asignar los días de clase de un profesor con un programa específico. **El problema** es que cuando selecciono los días de un programa se me modifican de los demás.

Así es la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al seleccionar los días del primer programa (con id 1801820)...

[image]

... automáticamente, se selecciona así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así queda la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí hay un ejemplo de la tabla:

```js
$(document).on("change", "#dias", function(e){
            var datos=$("#dias").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"consultas_externas.php",
                data:datos,
                success:function(data){
                }
            })
        })
```

```html
<table border="1" id="dias_in">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="8">DÍAS</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ficha</td>
            <td>Lunes</td>
            <td>Martes</td>
            <td>Miércoles</td>
            <td>Jueves</td>
            <td>Viernes</td>
            <td>Sábado</td>
            <td>Domingo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="number" style="text-align:center;" name="programa_asignado" value="1801820" readonly=""></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="lunes" unchecked=""></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="martes" unchecked=""></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="miercoles" unchecked=""></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="jueves" unchecked=""></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="viernes" unchecked=""></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="sabado" unchecked=""></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="domingo" unchecked=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="number" style="text-align:center;" name="programa_asignado" value="1503073" readonly=""></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="lunes" unchecked=""></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="martes" unchecked=""></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="miercoles" unchecked=""></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="jueves" unchecked=""></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="viernes" unchecked=""></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="sabado" unchecked=""></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="domingo" unchecked=""></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Y aquí lo recibo (.php):

```
if (isset($_POST['lunes']) || isset($_POST['martes']) || isset($_POST['miercoles']) || isset($_POST['jueves']) || isset($_POST['viernes']) || isset($_POST['sabado']) || isset($_POST['domingo']) && isset($_POST['programa_asignado']) && isset($_POST['documento_in_dia'])) {
    $lunes=$_POST['lunes'];
    $martes=$_POST['martes'];
    $miercoles=$_POST['miercoles'];
    $jueves=$_POST['jueves'];
    $viernes=$_POST['viernes'];
    $sabado=$_POST['sabado'];
    $domingo=$_POST['domingo'];
    $doc=$_POST['documento_in_dia'];
    $programa_asignado=$_POST['programa_asignado'];
    if ($lunes=="on") {
        $modificar_dias=mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE relacion_programas SET lunes='checked' WHERE cc_instructor='$doc' AND id_ficha='$programa_asignado'");
    }else{
        $modificar_dias=mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE relacion_programas SET lunes='unchecked' WHERE cc_instructor='$doc' AND id_ficha='$programa_asignado'");
    }
    if ($martes=="on") {
        $modificar_dias=mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE relacion_programas SET martes='checked' WHERE cc_instructor='$doc' AND id_ficha='$programa_asignado'");
    }else{
        $modificar_dias=mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE relacion_programas SET martes='unchecked' WHERE cc_instructor='$doc' AND id_ficha='$programa_asignado'");
    }
    if ($miercoles=="on") {
        $modificar_dias=mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE relacion_programas SET miercoles='checked' WHERE cc_instructor='$doc' AND id_ficha='$programa_asignado'");
    }else{
        $modificar_dias=mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE relacion_programas SET miercoles='unchecked' WHERE cc_instructor='$doc' AND id_ficha='$programa_asignado'");
    }
    if ($jueves=="on") {
        $modificar_dias=mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE relacion_programas SET jueves='checked' WHERE cc_instructor='$doc' AND id_ficha='$programa_asignado'");
    }else{
        $modificar_dias=mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE relacion_programas SET jueves='unchecked' WHERE cc_instructor='$doc' AND id_ficha='$programajueves'");
    }
    if ($viernes=="on") {
        $modificar_dias=mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE relacion_programas SET viernes='checked' WHERE cc_instructor='$doc' AND id_ficha='$programa_asignado'");
    }else{
        $modificar_dias=mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE relacion_programas SET viernes='unchecked' WHERE cc_instructor='$doc' AND id_ficha='$programa_asignado'");
    }
    if ($sabado=="on") {
        $modificar_dias=mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE relacion_programas SET sabado='checked' WHERE cc_instructor='$doc' AND id_ficha='$programa_asignado'");
    }else{
        $modificar_dias=mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE relacion_programas SET sabado='unchecked' WHERE cc_instructor='$doc' AND id_ficha='$programa_asignado'");
    }
    if ($domingo=="on") {
        $modificar_dias=mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE relacion_programas SET domingo='checked' WHERE cc_instructor='$doc' AND id_ficha='$programa_asignado'");
    }else{
        $modificar_dias=mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE relacion_programas SET domingo='unchecked' WHERE cc_instructor='$doc' AND id_ficha='$programa_asignado'");
    }
}
```

En verdad he intentado todo, pero no he podido lograr que se muestren bien los días. Agradecería mucho la ayuda, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Por que en tu `else` del `if ($jueves=="on") {` tienes `id_ficha='$programajueves'"` y en todos los demás `id_ficha='$programa_asignado'"`

Comment: Se me había pasado. Qué gran ojo tienes. Me evitaste un problema futuro. Muchas gracias, pero el error sigue apareciendo.

Comment: Isaias, las respuestas son para responder, no para preguntar. Si no puedes hacer comentarios aún, por tu reputación, hay formas de ganar reputación, como responder a preguntas de manera acertada o generar preguntas que sean bien recibidas. Un saludo.